# d3.js - Zoomable Circle Packing Percentage

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I am trying to use the visualization from [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/7607535) and I was hoping that someone could help me display the percentages.  I have managed to add the values by adding the following line of code:

`.text(function (d) { return d.name + ' (' + d.value + ') '; });`

And the above works flawlessly.  But, is there a way to display the percentages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a lack of details here so I am not sure if my answer is going to be helpful but... In order to display a percentage you need to have the max of d.value you can get, if so then just do a `Math.floor((currentValue / maxValue) * 100)`.